# why do I get name error while using dash with python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

- I am trying to plot live graphs onto a website using dash with python
- Using the latest version of Dash
- got to know the event was removed from the latest version

so now how do I approach this problem any help will be appreciated.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/rohit/PycharmProjects/flask-projects/pltexmple.py", line 28, in 
events=[Event('graph-update', 'interval')])
NameError: name 'Event' is not defined**

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque

X = deque(maxlen=20)
X.append(1)
Y = deque(maxlen=20)
Y.append(1)


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*1000
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph-update', 'interval')])
def update_graph_scatter():
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1]*random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))

    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            mode= 'lines+markers'
            )

    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807868/how-to-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-event-in-dash-from-plotly-python

Comment: hi, i tried to do it before but it gives me TypeError: update_graph_scatter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: I have updated the callback, can you confirm that is how i should do

Comment: The code line from the traceback does not appear in your code. Check if you posted the right code and add the full traceback to the question!

Comment: The edit looks good. One more thing, accept an argument in your function. `def update_graph_scatter(input_value):` and change `interval` to `n_intervals`

Comment: it works, Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event was removed in the latest version of the Dash, thats why you are getting an error.

Please change the code to the below one.

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque

X = deque(maxlen=20)
X.append(1)
Y = deque(maxlen=20)
Y.append(1)


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*1000
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph_scatter(input_data):
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1]*random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))

    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            mode= 'lines+markers'
            )

    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```